# Upload de arquivo em php para outro servidor

Tags: php, upload

Upload de aquivos pesados para outro servidor, utilizando PHP

Enviar arquivos do Autocad, e esses arquivos são pesados...queria saber se tem como o usuário entrar no site, no setor para enviar esses arquivos, ou seja, vai ter um formulário onde o usuário vai enviar esse arquivo e vai mandar para um servidor dentro da empresa.

Comment: Você precisa detalhar sua pergunta. Qual é exatamente sua dúvida?

Comment: Se pode enviar via FTP

Comment: Então seria interessante [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/20599/edit) sua pergunta para que ela fique mais clara

Comment: Enviar arquivos do Autocad, e esses arquivos são pesados...queria saber se tem como o usuário entrar no site, no setor para enviar esses arquivos, ou seja, vai ter um formulário onde o usuário vai enviar esse arquivo e vai mandar para um servidor dentro da empresa.

Comment: Ah, tá vendo, tem muito mais detalhes! Porfa, **[edit]e** a pergunta e inclua as novas informações.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função ftp_put caso queira realizar upload pelo FTP destes arquivos.

```
<?php
$file = 'somefile.txt';
$remote_file = 'readme.txt';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Fonte: Manual PHP disponível em http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Como são arquivos pesados considere utilizar ajax nas suas requisições e a função `set_time_limit` no lado do servidor.